# Calculate values of Möbius function

Tags: combinatorics, mobius-function

Let $(P,\leq)$ be a partial order with $P = \lbrace 0,1,2,3,4 \rbrace$ such that $0 \leq 1 \leq 4$,$0 \leq 2 \leq 4$,$0 \leq 3 \leq 4$. I want to calculate the values of the mobius function $\mu : P \times P \to \mathbb{R}$ of this partial order which is defined as the inverse of the zeta function
\begin{equation}
\zeta(x,y) = \begin{cases}
1 & x \leq y \\
0 & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
\end{equation}
Now I know that the mobius function must satisfy
\begin{align*}
\mu(x,x) &= 1, \\
\mu(x,y) &= -\sum_{x < z \leq y}\mu(z,y), \\
  \mu(x,y) &= -\sum_{x \leq z < y}\mu(x,z).
\end{align*}
So I get $\mu(i,i) = 1$ for all $i \in P$ and
since $0$ is a minimal element and $4$ a maximal
\begin{align}
\mu(x,x) &= 1 \mbox{ for all } x \in P, \\
\mu(x,0) &= 0, \mbox{ for all } x \in \lbrace 1,2,3,4 \rbrace,  \\
\mu(0,4) &= -(\mu(1,4) + \mu(2,4) + \mu(3,4) + 1), \\
\mu(0,4) &= -(1 + \mu(0,1) + \mu(0,2) + \mu(0,3)).
\end{align}
Since $i$ and $j$ for $i \neq j$ with $i,j \in \lbrace 1,2,3 \rbrace$ are not comparable we get
\begin{equation*}
  \mu(1,2) = \mu(2,1) = \mu(2,3) = \mu(3,2) = \mu(3,1) = \mu(1,3) = 0.
\end{equation*}
Now I stuck at calculating $\mu(1,4), \mu(2,4), \mu(3,4), \mu(0,1), \mu(0,2)$ and $\mu(0,3)$.

Edit: I think it works out if I use from
the definition of the mobius function
\begin{equation}
  \sum_{x \leq z \leq y}\mu(x,z) = \delta(x,y)
\end{equation}
and since only $i$ and $4$ are comparable with $i$ in the interval [i,4] and $0$ is the minimal element we get
\begin{align*}
  0 &= \delta(1,4) = \mu(1,1) + \mu(1,4), \\
  0 &= \delta(2,4) = \mu(2,2) + \mu(2,4), \\
  0 &= \delta(3,4) = \mu(3,3) + \mu(3,4)
\end{align*}
thus
\begin{equation*}
  \mu(1,4) = \mu(2,4) = \mu(3,4) = -1
\end{equation*}
therefore
\begin{equation*}
  \mu(0,4) = -\mu(1,4) - \mu(2,4) - \mu(3,4) - 1 = 2.
\end{equation*}
With the same strategy since $0$ is the minimal element and $4$ the maximal one has
\begin{align*}
  0 &= \delta(0,1) = \mu(0,0) + \mu(0,1), \\
  0 &= \delta(0,2) = \mu(0,0) + \mu(0,2), \\
  0 &= \delta(0,3) = \mu(0,0) + \mu(0,3)
\end{align*}
hence
\begin{equation*}
  \mu(0,1) = \mu(0,2) = \mu(0,3) = -1.
\end{equation*}

Comment: If $0\leq 1\leq 4$ then in the recursion that you write, the only element in the sum is $1<z\leq 4$ which implies that $z=4$ and $x=1$ and $y=4$ so $\mu (1,4)=-\mu (4,4)$. Can you do the rest?